# How would you successfully return the row name of the maximum value in a column based on conditions in the rest of the row?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

=INDEX(G27:H60, MATCH(MAX(M27:M60),M27:M60,0))

This is the formula I want to use, but with the MAX replaced with something that will only take the max based on certain conditions, listed below.

=MAXIFS(M27:M60,I27:I60,AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH("CADET",I27:I60)),ISNUMBER(MATCH("C/Amn",I27:I60)),ISNUMBER(MATCH("C/A1C",I27:I60)),ISNUMBER(MATCH("C/SrA",I27:I60))))

The thing is, the AND stuff returns TRUE, but then when it's put into MAXIFS, the MAXIFS formula just returns 0 instead of the max. How would I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168054/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  G27:H60, 
  M27:M60 
  = 
  max( 
    filter( 
      M27:M60, 
      regexmatch(I27:I60, "(?i)^(CADET|C/Amn|C/A1C|C/SrA)$") 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to edit that formula to do what I mentioned in the question edit?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry.